# cannot send message to weblogic queues

Tags: java, jms, weblogic

Iam trying to send a string message into a JMS queue created in weblogic server. Iam using Eclipse ide and when i run my web application i get the following error and the tomcat server gets shutdown.The error is

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.UnmarshalException: failed to unmarshal class weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedUser; nested exception is: 
    java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 31]
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ExceptionTranslator.toNamingException(ExceptionTranslator.java:74)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ExceptionTranslator.toNamingException(ExceptionTranslator.java:32)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.toNamingException(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:773)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.pushSubject(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:673)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.newContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:466)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:373)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:307)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:277)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.infotech.jms.JMSBEAQueueSend.sendMessage(JMSBEAQueueSend.java:48)
    at com.infotech.struts.actions.AppAction.execute(AppAction.java:75)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: failed to unmarshal class weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedUser; nested exception is: 
    java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 31
    at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:229)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef.invoke(BasicRemoteRef.java:224)
    at weblogic.common.internal.RMIBootServiceImpl_1001_WLStub.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.Security$1.run(Security.java:185)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.Security.authenticate(Security.java:181)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.authenticateRemotely(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:734)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.pushSubject(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:667)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 31
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:195)
    at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.readObject(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:565)
    at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:191)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.ObjectIO.readObject(ObjectIO.java:62)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:227)
    ... 37 more
```

Please help me out.Thanks and best regards

Comment: Please ask if any further info needed..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on a some quick research into this issue, it appears to be caused by using different JDK levels between the app server and the client.  Most of the examples I have seen have shown it to occur when using Java 6 on the client while running Weblogic on Java 5.

While I have not personally tried it, the recommendation is to add the following to your client application's startup command:

```
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true
```

Setting this property enables a backwards compatibility mode in the ClassLoader's loadClass method.

Here is a [link to an Oracle forum question](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4665385�) that provides some additional information.

Alternatively, you would have to look at making sure the client and server are running the same JVM level if you are performing direct integrations.  Obviously, this is not usually the optimal solution.

Comment: i'm using eclipse ide.. where do i need to add that startup comment?

Comment: If you are running your client from within Eclipse, then you would need to add this command to the Run Configuration for the client:  Right-click project and go to `Run As->Run Configurations`.  Select the run configuration for your client should be under `Java Application`.  Select the `arguments` tab and enter the testin in the `VM Arguments` text box.  This will allow the client to run with the `sun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax` system property set to `true`.  If you run your application from the command-line, then add the -D... text prior to your app execution, e.g., java -D... Main.

Comment: Finally resolved it, the problem was the eclipse by default used jdk 1.6, which i changed to 1.5 and it worked.Thanks for the help.