# "Invalid type code: FE" when sending message to Weblogic

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, weblogic-10.x

We are communicating with a Weblogic 10.3.5. When we send a message from our client, we get the following exception:

```
weblogic.utils.AssertionError: ***** ASSERTION FAILED *****
at weblogic.rjvm.ClusterInfoHelper.readClusterInfo(ClusterInfoHelper.java:32)
at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.readClusterInfo(ConnectionManager.java:981)
at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManagerClient.handleIdentifyResponse(ConnectionManagerClient.java:212)
at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.dispatch(ConnectionManager.java:875)
at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.dispatch(MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.java:512)
at weblogic.rjvm.t3.client.MuxableSocketT3.dispatch(MuxableSocketT3.java:303)
at weblogic.socket.BaseAbstractMuxableSocket.dispatch(BaseAbstractMuxableSocket.java:298)
at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocketOnce(SocketMuxer.java:950)
at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocket(SocketMuxer.java:888)
at weblogic.socket.JavaSocketMuxer.processSockets(JavaSocketMuxer.java:339)
at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteRequestAdapter.execute(ExecuteRequestAdapter.java:21)
at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)
at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: FE
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1374)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObjectFromPreDiabloPeer(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:232)
at weblogic.rjvm.ClusterInfoHelper.readClusterInfo(ClusterInfoHelper.java:30)
... 13 more
```

I already found the question [cannot send message to weblogic queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911027/cannot-send-message-to-weblogic-queues), but it does not really help me. At first WebLogic was running on a 1.6 JVM, while my client is on Java 1.7, but I tried running it with Java 1.7 getting the same result. Also note, that the type code in my exception differs from that in the question.

Interestingly, when I start a consumer for the same queue in the same JVM as the producer is, the exception is not being thrown, and messages are received and consumed without problem. Once the consumer is started in a different JVM, I get the exception in the producer.

Fresh out of ideas, so if anyone has something, I would be really grateful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

One important detail is, that I am using the Camel JMS component to publish the messages.
It turns out, that setting the "testConnectionOnStartup" option to true on the endpoint will make the error go away.

Some part of initializing the connection seems to be made when a consumer is created, but not when a producer is, therefore I got the exception while sending a message.

Hope this helps someone in a similar situation =)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. What Camel version did you use?

Comment: We are using Version 2.11.0