# ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, weblogic

I'm getting a ClientTransportException when try to access the webservice hosted in websphere (java 1.3), from a application deployed in a weblogic server (java 1.6). Webservice method has a return value of `Date` data type and generated sources in my application it is implemented as `Calender` datatype, how can I solve this. Thank you.

In generated sources:

```
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar someDate;
```

In hosted EJB:

```
public Date someMethod(){
   //return date;
}
```

Comment: 500 Internal server error is usually associated with some exception on the server side. Try to examine the server logs and find the root cause of the error.

Comment: Agree with Daniel - there has to be something more in one of the server logs. For instance, weblogic has known issues when the client and server are different versions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911027/cannot-send-message-to-weblogic-queues